With what part of the program are the stack and heap associated?
I understanding the stack, the LIFO working principle, memory allocation on the heap and stuff. My question is, where does this exists ?
Is there a dedicated region on the ram for the stack ? Or is it a layer of abstraction built over the ram, that is handles by the C compiler ? or is it something built into the OS or the CPU ?
I read this thread on a similar question, but it seems like everyone just avoided the relevant part.....
I have followed along with this video from Jacob Sorber, and added a few stuff to it too. Maybe it would help to know the history of the stack and the heap, and why the need for these structures was felt, along with, at which level of the computer are they actually implemented.

This is more a computer architecture question than a computer programming question. The answer will vary depending on the processor. Some have an architectural stack. Some have a stack by convention. Some have no stack at all.

As to the "why the need", why would you use global "space" for local data?
